# Failing tests allowed in Bamboo?

Tags: junit, continuous-integration, bamboo

Is it possible to somehow set a threshold for JUnit test cases that would stop Bamboo from failing a build when there are failing tests?

I know about the 'Quarantine' option, but it is not exactly what I am looking for. I do not want to have to manually move the test cases from the quarantined set. We have a TDD environment, where the test cases are based on a large set of external, annotated data, and we want to build up the coverage.

I want to see the actual results (e.g.: 43% pass) and tell Bamboo to succeed the build e.g. when the results are >40%.

By the way, if I stick to Quarantine, do I really have to pick them one by one? There are 10,000! :D

Comment: Your update is exactly how I would have solved this: custom failure requirements are best handled with an intermediate script. Consider adding it as an answer.

Comment: So did you end up building another app that can render real results ?

Comment: I added a script after the tests are run and before letting Bamboo interpret the results. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Bamboo does not support this use case. There are some plugins that try to deal with this.

What I finally did was to create an intermediate script that parses the test results (JUnit XML). There are three scenarios here:

- all test pass: the XML is left as is
- there are too many failing tests: the XML is left as is (the build will fail)
- there are failing tests, but their number does not exceed the set threshold: the XML contents are substituted with "passing" contents so that Bamboo does not fail the build